# Using different versions of class with static method

Tags: c#, class, static-methods

I use some library which has class with static method.

```
namespace lib
{
    public class libClass
    {
        ...
        public static int num;
        public static void libMethod(int arg)
        {
            num = arg;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to use two instances of this class in two different places of my program (in different namespaces). The problem is that this instances should be independent from each other (libClass.num can be different).

I'll be glad if you help me deal with the problem. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? You wish to call the 'libClass.libMethod' from two different namespaces?

Comment: I think he's concerned that if he references `libClass.num` it will hold the same value in both namespaces. @Centuri0n: Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: This can technically be done by creating another AppDomain.  Whether that's a viable solution is entirely unguessable from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear why you are in this situation, ie. what you can and can not do.

Ideally, I would just create an instance of the class, and avoid the whole problem, but I assume there is some reason you can't or do not want to do this?

Otherwise the simplest and cleanest way to solve this might be to just make two copies of the class, and put one in each namespace, each with their own static variable. 
I would strongly recomend giving the classes different names too, just to be clear and avoid confusion later.

Your final option is to look for a completely different solution. Hard to say without knowing more about your scenario, but if you really can't use an instance, then it seems like `num` should perhaps not be the responsibility of this class at all.

Obviously, you want to store and use `num` in some logical context/scope; You should ask yourself which other options (other than that class) you have for doing that within your scope (hope that was not too abstract ^^).

**UPDATE:**

I see what you mean now. I think you should be able to override the class however. Try something like this:

```
    using VariousTesting;

    namespace VariousTesting
    {
    public class LibClass
        {        
            public static int num;
            public static void libMethod(int arg)
            {
                num = arg;
            }
        }
    }

    namespace VariousTesting2
    {
        public class SubLibClassA : LibClass
        {

            public static int num;
            public static void libMethod(int arg)
            {
                num = arg;
            }

            public static int GetNum()
            {
                return num;
            }
        }
    }

    namespace VariousTesting2
    {
        public class SubLibClassB : LibClass
        {
            public static int num;
            public static void libMethod(int arg)
            {
                num = arg;
            }

            public static int GetNum()
            {
                return num;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can test it as follows:

```
        SubLibClassA.libMethod(1);
        Console.WriteLine(SubLibClassA.GetNum());  // 1

        SubLibClassB.libMethod(2);
        Console.WriteLine(SubLibClassB.GetNum());  // 2
        Console.WriteLine(SubLibClassA.GetNum()); // still 1! Yay! :D
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can't create copies of the class because I have just dll with it and haven't its source code (and that is why I can't change structure of the class). I didn't get solution with creating instances - libClass.num is static and will be the same for all instances.

Comment: It is almost what I need! But there is another problem, as I said, I haven't code of `libMethod`, the only thing I know it somehow changes `num`. Could it be override in this case?

Comment: @centuri0n: You can decompile the 3rd party DLL with [ilSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to see how it uses the `num` variable. However you should be still able to create a new class and override `num` by inheriting it as in Kjartan's example `public class SubLibClassA : LibClass`